# Custom IScrollInfo panel loses scrolling ability when hosted in an ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, panel, scrollviewer, itemscontrol

I'm trying to create a custom panel using the [`IScrollInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.iscrollinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) interface, with little success. I can get it to work if I manually declare items within the custom panel in XAML, but when I put it into an `ItemsControl`, the scrolling ability stops. I'd really appreciate it if someone would show me where I've gone wrong. Here is the (quite lengthy, but simple) code for the panel:

```
using IScrollInfoExample.Extentions;
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace IScrollInfoExample
{
    public class ExampleScrollPanel : Panel, IScrollInfo
    {
        private TranslateTransform _trans = new TranslateTransform();
        private Size _extent = new Size(0, 0);
        private Size _viewport = new Size(0, 0);
        private Point _offset;
        private const double _scrollAmount = 3;

        public ExampleScrollPanel()
        {
            Loaded += ExampleScrollPanel_Loaded;
            RenderTransform = (_trans = new TranslateTransform());
        }

        public bool CanHorizontallyScroll { get; set; } = false;

        public bool CanVerticallyScroll { get; set; } = true;

        public double HorizontalOffset
        {
            get { return _offset.X; }
        }

        public double VerticalOffset
        {
            get { return _offset.Y; }
        }

        public double ExtentHeight
        {
            get { return _extent.Height; }
        }

        public double ExtentWidth
        {
            get { return _extent.Width; }
        }

        public double ViewportHeight
        {
            get { return _viewport.Height; }
        }

        public double ViewportWidth
        {
            get { return _viewport.Width; }
        }

        public ScrollViewer ScrollOwner { get; set; }

        public void LineUp()
        {
            SetVerticalOffset(VerticalOffset - _scrollAmount);
        }

        public void PageUp()
        {
            SetVerticalOffset(VerticalOffset - _viewport.Height);
        }

        public void MouseWheelUp()
        {
            SetVerticalOffset(VerticalOffset - _scrollAmount);
        }

        public void LineDown()
        {
            SetVerticalOffset(VerticalOffset + _scrollAmount);
        }

        public void PageDown()
        {
            SetVerticalOffset(VerticalOffset + _viewport.Height);
        }

        public void MouseWheelDown()
        {
            SetVerticalOffset(VerticalOffset + _scrollAmount);
        }

        public void LineLeft()
        {
            SetHorizontalOffset(HorizontalOffset - _scrollAmount);
        }

        public void PageLeft()
        {
            SetHorizontalOffset(HorizontalOffset - _viewport.Width);
        }

        public void MouseWheelLeft()
        {
            LineLeft();
        }

        public void LineRight()
        {
            SetHorizontalOffset(HorizontalOffset + _scrollAmount);
        }

        public void PageRight()
        {
            SetHorizontalOffset(HorizontalOffset + _viewport.Width);
        }

        public void MouseWheelRight()
        {
            LineRight();
        }

        public Rect MakeVisible(Visual visual, Rect rectangle)
        {
            return new Rect();
        }

        public void SetHorizontalOffset(double offset)
        {
            if (offset < 0 || _viewport.Width >= _extent.Width)
            {
                offset = 0;
            }
            else if (offset + _viewport.Width >= _extent.Width)
            {
                offset = _extent.Width - _viewport.Width;
            }
            _offset.X = offset;
            if (ScrollOwner != null) ScrollOwner.InvalidateScrollInfo();
            _trans.X = -offset;
        }

        public void SetVerticalOffset(double offset)
        {
            offset = CoerceVerticalOffset(offset);
            _offset.Y = offset;
            _trans.Y = -offset;
            if (ScrollOwner != null) ScrollOwner.InvalidateScrollInfo();
        }

        private double CoerceVerticalOffset(double offset)
        {
            if (offset < 0 || _viewport.Height >= _extent.Height)
            {
                offset = 0;
            }
            else if (offset + _viewport.Height >= _extent.Height)
            {
                offset = _extent.Height - _viewport.Height;
            }
            return offset;
        }

        private void ExampleScrollPanel_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ScrollViewer scrollOwner = this.GetParentOfType<ScrollViewer>();
            if (scrollOwner != null) ScrollOwner = scrollOwner;
        }

        protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
        {
            UpdateScrollInfo(availableSize);
            Size totalSize = new Size();
            foreach (UIElement child in InternalChildren)
            {
                child.Measure(availableSize);
                totalSize.Height += child.DesiredSize.Height;
                totalSize.Width = Math.Max(totalSize.Width, child.DesiredSize.Width);
            }
            return base.MeasureOverride(totalSize);
        }

        protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
        {
            UpdateScrollInfo(finalSize);
            double verticalPosition = 0;

            int childCount = InternalChildren.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++)
            {
                UIElement child = InternalChildren[i];
                child.Arrange(new Rect(0, verticalPosition, finalSize.Width, finalSize.Height));
                verticalPosition += child.DesiredSize.Height;
            }
            return base.ArrangeOverride(finalSize);
        }

        private void UpdateScrollInfo(Size availableSize)
        {
            bool viewportChanged = false, extentChanged = false;
            Size extent = CalculateExtent(availableSize);
            if (extent != _extent)
            {
                _extent = extent;
                extentChanged = true;
            }
            if (availableSize != _viewport)
            {
                _viewport = availableSize;
                viewportChanged = true;
            }
            if (extentChanged || viewportChanged) ScrollOwner?.InvalidateScrollInfo();
        }

        private Size CalculateExtent(Size availableSize)
        {
            Size totalExtentSize = new Size();
            foreach (UIElement child in InternalChildren)
            {
                child.Measure(availableSize);
                totalExtentSize.Height += child.DesiredSize.Height;
                totalExtentSize.Width = Math.Max(totalExtentSize.Width, child.DesiredSize.Width);
            }
            return totalExtentSize;
        }
    }
}
```

Now `MainWindow.xaml.cs`:

```
<Window x:Class="IScrollInfoExample.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:Local="clr-namespace:IScrollInfoExample"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Buttons, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Local:MainWindow}}}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Local:ExampleScrollPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Height="100" Width="250" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="{Binding}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
        <!--<Local:ExampleScrollPanel>
            <Button Height="100" Width="250" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="A" />
            <Button Height="100" Width="250" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="B" />
            <Button Height="100" Width="250" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="C" />
            <Button Height="100" Width="250" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="D" />
            <Button Height="100" Width="250" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="E" />
            <Button Height="100" Width="250" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="F" />
            <Button Height="100" Width="250" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="G" />
            <Button Height="100" Width="250" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="H" />
            <Button Height="100" Width="250" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="I" />
        </Local:ExampleScrollPanel>-->
    </ScrollViewer>
</Window>
```

And the code behind:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;

namespace IScrollInfoExample
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Buttons = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            IEnumerable<int> characterCodes = Enumerable.Range(65, 26);
            foreach (int characterCode in characterCodes) Buttons.Add(((char)characterCode).ToString().ToUpper());
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Buttons), typeof(ObservableCollection<string>), typeof(MainWindow), null);

        public ObservableCollection<string> Buttons
        {
            get { return (ObservableCollection<string>)GetValue(ButtonsProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ButtonsProperty, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

Looking at the XAML first, you can see the manually added `Button` objects. Run the application  and you should see some vertically scrollable buttons in a panel... so far, so good. If you put a breakpoint in the `MouseWheelUp` or `MouseWheelDown` methods and scroll, you'll notice that the breakpoint gets hit instantly.

Now if you comment out the lower `ExampleScrollPanel` with its manually created buttons and uncomment the `ItemsControl` above, you'll see that the ability to scroll the items has disappeared. My question is "*How can I make the scrolling work when the custom panel is hosted within an `ItemsControl` element?*"

Please note that `ScrollOwner` property is populated using a custom `GetParentOfType<T>` method, which finds the appropriate `ScrollViewer` successfully, and is not the cause of this problem. As such, I have not included the `VisualTreeHelper`-based code for this method.

Also, I noticed that the scroll bars no longer appear once the panel is within the `ItemsControl`, but I checked and the `extent` and `viewport` values of the panel still seem to be getting updated successfully. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ItemsControl` does not have it's own `ScrollViewer` and it cannot access the external one that you have provided for that purpose. You need to add the `ScrollViewer` where the `ItemsControl` can access it, using the `ItemsControl.Template` property, like so:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Buttons, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
    AncestorType={x:Type Local:MainWindow}}}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Local:ExampleScrollPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.Template>

        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}">

            <!--Add the ScrollViewer here, inside the ControlTemplate-->
            <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True">

                <!--Your items will be added here-->
                <ItemsPresenter/> 

            </ScrollViewer>

        </ControlTemplate>

    </ItemsControl.Template>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Height="100" Width="250" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                Content="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Note that you must set the [`CanContentScroll` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.cancontentscroll(v=vs.110).aspx) of the `ScrollViewer` to `True` to inform it that you have implemented the `IScrollInfo` interface in your panel and want to take over the scrolling function.

Comment: That works perfectly now. Thanks so much, I've been stuck on this problem for ages!